# uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' must initialize PFFacebookUtils with a call to +initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions'

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

Working on my first ios app (actually first app  ever)! I'm trying to implement a facebook login screen that works with Parse's PFUser.

I have a UIButton "Login with Facebook" that is connected to an action with the following code:

```
-(IBAction) facebookLogin:(id)sender {

[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:self.permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
    }
}];
}
```

Where I had

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *permissions;
```

and

```
self.permissions = @[@"public_profile"];
```

So it runs fine, but when I press the "Login with FaceBook" button in the Ios Simulator, the app terminates and I see the following in the terminal:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You must initialize PFFacebookUtils with a call to +initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions'

This doesn't make sense to me because in my AppDelegate.m file I had initialized Facebook:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


[Parse enableLocalDatastore];


[Parse setApplicationId:@"..."
              clientKey:@"..."];

return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

return 1;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second example code is correct it will return at the statement:

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
```

and not execute the following lines. Remove the `return` from that statement so the folloowing statement will execute.

Also since:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

must return a `BOOL` the return statement should be `YES`, not `1`. Booleans in Objectice are `YES` and `NO`.